# How do I write data on a nfc tag in a fragments?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-viewpager, fragment, nfc

My starting point was here https://github.com/rudsonlive/Navigation-Drawer-ActionBarCompat implementing a new app with nfc writing support.

Now I want to implement writing data on nfc tags. Therefor I am using different fragments for different kind of data (e.g. one fragment to write contact data on a nfc tag, the next fragment to write specific application data on a nfc tag, and so on).

For another app I successfully implemented this, but for the setting up the app with fragments I fail.

This is how I implemented tag writing within an activity. Showing an AlertDialog to inform the user to approach a tag and handling the specific intent.

```
enableTagWriteMode();
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(NfcDialogActivity.this).setTitle("Approach Tag").setOnCancelListener(
    new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            disableTagWriteMode();
        }
    });
alert = ad.create();
alert.show();
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Tag writing mode
    if (mWriteMode && NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Tag detectedTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        if (writeTag(mNdefMessage, detectedTag)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Writing complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            alert.cancel();
        } 
    }
}
```

Could someone give me an advise how to write tags as mentioned above within a fragment?

Thanks in advance & sry for my english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delegate your Intent from your Activity for it to be processed by your Fragments. onNewIntent() for getting NFC Intents only works for Activities. So when an NFC Intent occurrs, you have to make sure to send it to your Fragments when they're ready (e.g. by getting the Intent by getActivity().getIntent() from within your Fragments).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice! Figured out, that it is necessary to implement the onNewIntent() method like

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: Did you keep only this onNewIntent part in the activity or all the other part of NFC?